# Adding two functions?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, functor, addition

I just browsed through "C# in Depth" and stumbled upon the following code:

```
Func<string> stringFunc = () => "";
Func<object> objectFunc = () => new object();
Func<object> combined = objectFunc + stringFunc;
```

I'm pretty sure that adding two functions is meaningless in mathematics, so why would any programmer want an overload of the binary `operator+` for functions? This seems to be a perfect example of why overloading operators *can* do harm (and I generally support the idea of operator overloading).

1. What does it mean to add two functions in C#? (I'm a C# noob, so bear with me.)
2. Do you agree that it was a design mistake to overload `operator+` here?
3. What would be a better syntactic to achieve whatever it is `operator+` does here?

Comment: You usually don't use `MultiCastDelegates` with functions that return anything(return-type isn't `void`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `delegate1 + delegate2` will create a third delegate instance which combines the first two, calling all functions in both delegates.
It's primarily intended for events.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx)

Comment: Aha, so it's like lifting (Haskell) the comma operator (C++)? :) The result of the first function is silently ignored, then? Feels highly confusing to me to use `operator+` for the purpose of "method chaining", but maybe that's just me...

Comment: @FredOverflow delegates don't usually return anything, so there would normally be nothing to ignore.

Comment: @alex: Really? So if I add two `Func<string>`, I get a `Func<void>` (instead of a `Func<string>`)?

Comment: @Fred: Delegate addition is usually used with void delegates (for event handlers)

Comment: Aha, so the example is unrealistic. Fair enough. Still, I find it alarming that `T + T` does not return a `T` (which is what you'd expect from `operator+`, right?).

Comment: @Fred: `T + T` does return `T`.

Comment: Please clarify with an example. What exactly happens with the results of the two functors that I combine? Is one of them ignored and the other simply handed through? Or is the result a combination of both results?

Comment: @Fred: All of the functions are called.  If they're non-`void`, the last return value is returned.

Comment: Use of `+` for this purpose seems pretty natural and intuitive to me

Answer (score 2):

Adding two functions is perfectly meaningful in mathematics. When you take the view that functions are operators then the space of all such operators is a linear space (under certain conditions). This is a very productive standpoint that yields a lot of useful mathematical insight.

Of course, that's not what's happening here, but I wanted to put you right on the mathematical side of your question!

Comment: Can you clarify with an example? What does `binary plus` + `binary multiply` mean?

Comment: I can see how you could reasonably define, say addition, on a space of functions with identical domains and co-domains, but in this case the functions have different co-domains?

Comment: @FredOverflow: In that case, there is a possible definition. `(plus + multiply): (x, y) -> plus( x, y ) + multiply(x, y)`

Comment: Consider the space of all linear functions from R^n to R^n. For example, if n is 3 then you can regard this space being populated by all 3x3 real matrices. These functions themselves form a linear space over the real field - consider scalar mult. and matrix addition as your operators.